# canvas element rendition like bit.ly

Tags: javascript, canvas

I've been asked to create the same ripple effect as the one found with the bit.ly 404 page: http://bit.ly/khgefiyueagf734

Javascript and canvas are pretty new to me and I am having this problem. When I change the image to one that I want. Not the fish one that is on the 404 page it renders the image as the same size as the fish and wont change.

**Can you tell me how to change the size of the ship (bit.ly fish) image?**

Here is the JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UzpAw/8/

and Here is the javascript that comes with it:

```
 (function() {
    function F() {
      if (g.getContext) {
        var a, b = a = 0;
        if (document.documentElement && (document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.documentElement.clientHeight)) a = document.documentElement.clientWidth, b = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        if (document.body && (document.body.clientWidth || document.body.clientHeight)) a = Math.max(a, document.body.clientWidth), b = Math.max(b, document.body.clientHeight);
        a = [a, b];
        e = a[1];
        d = a[0] + 1;
        r = Math.floor(0.5 * e);
        i = e - r;
        j = i - G;
        g.setAttribute("width", d);
        g.setAttribute("height",
        e);
        g.style.width = d + "px";
        g.style.height = e + "px";
        s = [Math.floor(0.75 * d), 0];
        c = g.getContext("2d");
        c.fillStyle = "#00022f";  //rgba(104,168,220,.8)
        v()
      }
    }
    function v() {
      c.fillRect(0, i, d, e - j)
    }
    function m(a, b) {
      if (!w) k.style.top = "-9999px", k.style.left = "-9999px",k.style.height = "20px", c.clearRect(0, j, d, e - j);
      c.clearRect(s[0], s[1] - 5, n[0], n[1]);
      a = a || Math.floor(0.6 * d);
      b = b || 0;
      b += r - 0.5 * n[1];
      c.drawImage(k, a, b, n[0], n[1]);
      s = [a, b];
      w || (v(), w = !0)
    }
    function O() {
      midPointY = Math.sin(h * 10 * P) * (o - h) * Q;
      h <= o && (f[p] = [0, midPointY], h % 9 == 0 && h % 2 == 1 && (f[z] = [-1, midPointY], z++));
      c.clearRect(0, j, d, e - j);
      m(Math.floor(0.6 * d), h < o ? Math.floor(midPointY) : 0);
      c.beginPath();
      c.moveTo(0, i);
      for (var a = [0, i], b = 0; b < t; b++) if (f[b]) {
        b < p && (f[b][0] = f[b][0] * R - H, f[p - b + p] = [-f[b][0], f[b][1]]);
        var q = f[b][0] + I,
          A = f[b][1] + i;
        c.bezierCurveTo((q - a[0]) / 2 + a[0], a[1], q - (q - a[0]) / 2, A, q, A);
        a[0] = q;
        a[1] = A
      }
      c.lineTo(d, i);
      c.lineTo(d, e);
      c.lineTo(0, e);
      c.closePath();
      c.fill();
      h++;
      h == o && (B = !1);
      h >= o * 2 && clearInterval(C)
    }
    function D(a, b) {
      if (!J) return !1;
      b && c.clearRect(x, y, b.w, b.h);
      a = a || E[0];
      x = K[0];
      y = K[1] + a.mt;
      c.drawImage(l, Math.abs(a.l),
      Math.abs(a.t), a.w, a.h, x, y, a.w, a.h)
    }
    function S() {
      var a = -1,
        b = 0,
        c = E.length,
        d;
      clearInterval(L);
      L = setInterval(function() {
        b = ++a > c - 1 ? c * 2 - 2 - a : a;
        d = E[b];
        D(d, M);
        M = d;
        a >= c * 2 - 2 && (a = 0)
      }, 200)
    }
    var u = function(a, b, c) {
      var d = c,
        c = function(b) {
          d.call(a, b)
        };
      return a.attachEvent ? a.attachEvent("on" + b, c) : a.addEventListener(b, c, !1)
    };
    if (!window.getComputedStyle) window.getComputedStyle = function(a) {
      return a.currentStyle
    };
    var t = 13,
      Q = 0.3,
      d = 960,
      e = 600,
      G = 30,
      r = Math.floor(0.5 * e),
      R = 1.01,
      H = 20,
      i = e - r,
      j = i - G,
      o = (t - 3) * 9,
      p = Math.floor(t / 2),
      I, g,
      c, C, B = !1,
      P = Math.PI / 180,
      f, z, h, k, s = [Math.floor(0.75 * d), 0],
      n = [236, 195],
      w, l, L, J, M, K = [10, 10], // 75, 150
      E = [{
        h: 58,
        w: 140,
        t: 0,
        l: 0,
        mt: 10
      }, {
        h: 72,
        w: 150,
        t: -64,
        l: 0,
        mt: 0
      }, {
        h: 61,
        w: 150,
        t: -151,
        l: 0,
        mt: 30
      }],
      N = !1;
    g = document.createElement("canvas");
    g.getContext && (N = !0, document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById("ripple")), g.setAttribute("id", "ripple"), document.body.appendChild(g), k = document.getElementById("ship"));
    //, l = document.getElementById("gull"), l.setAttribute("src", "/static/graphics/gulls-404.png")
    N && (function() {
      try {
        if (fish.complete) m();
        else if (parseInt(15, 5)) setTimeout(m, 1E3); // 15 IS: getComputedStyle(k).height
        else throw "no ship";
      } catch (a) {
        u(k, "load", function() {
          m()
        })
      }

      u(document.getElementById("ripple-control"), "mouseover", function(a) {
        if (g.getContext && !B) clearInterval(C), p = Math.floor(t / 2), I = a.pageX, z = 1, h = 0, f = [], f[0] = [H, 0], C = setInterval(O, 30), B = !0
      });
      u(window, "resize", function() {
        F();
        m();
        v();
        D()
      })
    }(), F());
    (function() {
      var a = 0,
        b = document.getElementById("cloud1"),
        c = document.getElementById("cloud2"),
        e = parseInt(getComputedStyle(b).left, 10),
        f = parseInt(getComputedStyle(c).left, 10);
      setInterval(function() {
        if (++a == 2) a = 0, e += 1, b.style.left = e + "px";
        f += 1;
        c.style.left = f + "px";
        e > d + 50 && (e = -200);
        f > d + 50 && (f = -100)
      }, 50)
    })()
  })();
```

**You have to hover over the blue to get the image to show** but as you can see, the size of the ship is way too large. I need it to be: 183x116.

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: It appears that you're trying to de-minify code that has been copyrighted by John Pezzetti.  **Please don't steal.**  Perhaps contact John and maybe he'll be willing to give you the code to use: http://www.otherhalffull.com

Comment: While you should always check out the license in this case I believe its code anyone can use as John put up a tutorial here with the code as well http://www.johnpezzetti.com/2011/01/25/html5-canvas-tutorial-creating-a-2-dimensional-wave under gnu public license

Comment: @markE The code is free to use. I checked this out. The question that I need is simply to change the image size. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Loktar, thanks for easing my mind!  I guess the OP just enjoys using minified code (or hadn't yet found the public-use deminified code in your link). ;-)

Comment: @markE haha yeah thats why I looked real quick I was considering a dv/cv on the question but then found that.

Answer (score 0):

The size of the ship is controlled by the variable on line#110.